# logstash to receive log from android? or is this elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm still a bit confused after reading documentation provided by logstash. I'm planning on writing an Android app, and I want to log the activity of the app. Logs will be sent over the network. is logstash not the right solution? because it needs to have an "agent" installed on systems that produces log.

I want a system that can store log from the app activity, but it also needs to be able to export the collected logs into plain text file. I know logstash can output to elasticsearch, but i'm not sure if it can export to plaintext file at the same time. or is this a task that ElasticSearch should do?

thanks a ton for any input you can provide

Comment: This is confugiration for Logstash on Android: [LogstashAndroid](https://gist.github.com/PatrykGala/55603fe4259d812fdc0ffbc9e63eaabc)

Comment: @PatrykG, is there any relationship to the efforts by [CoryBondor](https://github.com/CoryBond) regarding [logtash - Install plugin fails](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3367) or the logger service [android-logstash-logger](https://github.com/Labgoo/android-logstash-logger) by[zivsegal](https://github.com/zivsegal)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Logstash forwarder isn't currently available for android/ios unfortunately, nor could I find any existing solution for it from the community. (I asked the same question here but was voted off-topic because it was deemed asking for tool/library suggestions).
Your best bet unfortunately is either to write one yourself (which isn't trivial: you'll need to factor in offline connectivity, batching, scheduling, compressions, file-tracking, and so on), or to use other (usually commercial) logging services such as LogEntries.
By the way, the android/ios clients for LogEntries is open source. I'm not clear on its OSS licensing, but if you're to write an agent for logstash yourself, you could perhaps start by looking at LogEntries' android agent implementation, which already solves all the technical problems mentioned above. https://github.com/logentries/le_android.

And to answer your other question, yes logstash should receive your log (from the mobile-device), usually via lumberjack input (aka logstash forwarder). Logstash can then persist & index these log files to elasticsearch, providing it's configured that way

Comment: What about using the Logstash HTTP input plugin?  https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin

Comment: Yea you can use HTTP or TCP endpoint on the server side. But you just have to build the client-agent yourself, i.e. to load your log entries on the device yourself, tail it, filter it, batch it, compress it, throttle it, schedule it (offline/online, mobile/wifi), retry it, append it with metadata (IP, device models, OS version), anonymise it, etc.

In the PC world, that's what logstash agent does. Can't find any existing solution on the mobile world for logstash.